# Where is located the Initial Breakpoint?

Tags: windows, debugging

I am writing a simple debugger for learning purposes. I need to know where the Initial Breakpoint set by Windows is located to handle it properly. Read somewhere that is should be at the function `DbgBreakPoint()` from `ntdll.dll`, however that function resolves to address `0x77ab0a60` and from my tests the Initial Breakpoint always raises at address `0x77aedbcf`. Is this a function or just some random address with an `INT 3` instruction? If I am not mistaken `ntdll.dll` is always loaded at the same address, if so do programs always break at this exact address, or is there a variation?

Comment: This is not clear.  Windows does not set an initial breakpoint.  The debugger itself sets breakpoints.

Comment: Doesn't the debugger determine where any breakpoint is set (including the initial one)? If you want to learn how a Win32 debugger works, get a copy of John Robbins' "Debugging Applications for Microsoft .NET and Microsoft Windows".  Chapter 4 has example code for basic debuggers.  Amazon has used stock of the book for $6 plus shipping.

Comment: windows no set any *Initial Breakpoint*. all brealpoints debugger set yourself. good debugger must debug from first instruction in user mode - `LdrInitializeThunk`

Comment: @MichaelBurr That book also mentions this Initial Breakpoint. Also calling it _loader breakpoint_. Check chapter 4, section MinDBG. After some tables (at page 153 here) it says: `The only Win32 debug event that needs special handling is the loader breakpoint, which is also referred to as the initial breakpoint.`

Comment: @Kei - this "intial brealpoint" is function inside ntdll. say `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` (name can be different in different versions). it called if program start under debugger. however debugger yourself can set breakpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

process in user mode begin execute from `LdrInitializeThunk`, it call `LdrpInitializeProcess`. this routine, after load all static dependencies but before call it initialization routines - check are debugger present (`BeingDebugged` member of `PEB`) and if yes - call `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` where exist `int 3` instruction. in case wow64 process the `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` will be called 2 time - from 64 and 32 bit dll. as result 64-bit debugger got 2 breakpoints - `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` and `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT`.

how handle this - already debugger must select yourself. interactive debugger simply stop here. another debugger tools, usually simply skip(handle) **first** `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` (and `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT`) by returning `DBG_CONTINUE`

Comment: There's also a conditional break in `kernel32!_BaseDllInitialize`. It executes if `DebugFlags` is set in the `ProcessParameters`, a field that is normally 0, even when being debugged (i.e. it doesn't duplicate the functionality of `BeingDebugged` in the PEB). It's also checked by native applications in their `NtProcessStartup` entry point (or equivalent). IIRC, Session Manager (smss.exe) supports setting this field if an optional "debug" keyword is included in the command line arguments for a native boot execute application.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, executed `int 3`in `kernel32!_BaseDllInitialize` based on `DebugFlags` (even if no debugger attached). it executed (if executed) before `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` because `ntdll` early load `kernel32.dll` if not native subsystem. however `ProcessParameters` not direct accessed via `CreateProcess[Internal]` and as result very rarely used (if used at all). forget about this.  `NtProcessStartup` this is optional native mini-crt if we use `nt.lib`. however use this is optional, possible write native app with own entry point

Comment: I'd expect you of all people to appreciate the possibility of calling `RtlCreateUserProcess[Ex]` with custom process parameters. ;-)  As for native boot applications, yes, a custom entry point can be used, so this isn't necessarily OS behavior for all native applications. I found where I came across the connection to the Session Manager. It was in the source for ReactOS -- see [`SmpParseCommandLine`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d2d/smutil_8c.html#a6cb85934ec3f927f4e332ca4cc8fd0a3) and [`SmpExecuteCommand`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d42/smss_8c.html#ab1a7b5b0944875fd074fd32b0d0b2049).

Comment: @eryksun - how use `RtlCreateUserProcess` describe in details for example Gary Nebbett in `Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference`. however at that time - need notify csr after this, by used complex and undocumented  Csr api. than how process created serious changed, new api added. enough volatile area, from another side very rarely need extra functional than give `CreateProcessInternal` begin from vista. for xp (say for change parent) can and you hook